# How to completely access android bluetooth using progressive web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have tried web Bluetooth API to access,but it is only for battery status, heart rate etc.., I need to access complete functionality of Bluetooth. Is there any option or API available

Comment: What do you mean by "complete functionality of Bluetooth?"

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no other available API for this bluetooth function, The Web Bluetooth API is your only option, but it is not finalized yet.

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web), until now, the ability to interact with bluetooth devices has been possible only for native apps. The Web Bluetooth API aims to change this and brings it to web browsers as well. Alongside efforts like [Physical Web](https://google.github.io/physical-web/), people can walk up to and interact with devices straight from the web.

And even though it is not finalized yet, the Chrome Team is actively looking for enthusiastic developers to try out this work-in-progress API and give [feedback on the spec](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues) and [feedback on the implementation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry?components=Blink%3EBluetooth).

> Just take note that [Web Bluetooth
>   API](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) is currently
>   available to be enabled experimentally on your origin in Origin
>   Trials, or locally on your machine using an experimental flag. The
>   implementation is partially complete and currently available on Chrome
>   OS, Chrome for Android M, Linux, and Mac.

For more information, just read these [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3obFcCw8mk). You can also check the updates of the documents [here](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/commits/gh-pages).